# Why returns different value when use & operator in JavaScript and C#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have worked the same process in JavaScript and C# with the & operator, but the result was different.

**C# Code**

```
Int64 x = (634586400000000000 & 4611686018427387903);
x= 634586400000000000;
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var x = (634586400000000000 & 4611686018427387903);
x= 0;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ... because JavaScript and C# are different languages?

Answer (score 5):

[Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators) in javascript convert the operands to signed 32-bit integers (from the native IEEE 754 floats numbers are stored in).

Comment: A library like [bigInt.js](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html) might help here, although I haven't personally tried it.

Comment: That means you cannot perform any biwise operations on numbers larger than (roughly) 2 billion or lower than (roughly) -2 billion. If you do, behaviour is not defined.

Comment: Actually behaviour is well defined. From "Javascript: The Defenitive Guide", page 73: "If the bitwise operators are used with operands that are not integers or too large to fit in a 32-bit integer representation, they simply coerce the operand to 32-bit integers by dropping of any fractional part of the operand or any bits beyond the 32nd."

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're exceeding JavaScript's maximum integer value.  The maximum supported value for JavaScript integers is spec'd at 2^53.

UPDATE:

My initial response here wasn't correct - the issue is not JavaScript's max integer value, it's the max value of each operand handled by the ampersand op:

```
var biggest = 4294967291; // maximum 32 bit unsigned integer
alert(biggest & 1); // alerts 1
alert((biggest + 1) & 1); // alerts 0
```

Happy coding!

B

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise operators deal with a maximum of 32bits. I don't know how defined the behaviour is when asking it to deal with larger values.